# How can I increase both list at once?

Tags: c#

So here is 2 classes:

```
public class Student
{
    private string studentName;
    List<Classroom> attendingClassroom = new List<Classroom>();

    public string StudentName { get => studentName; private set => studentName = value; }

    public Student(string studentName)
    {
        StudentName = studentName;
    }

    public void AttendToClassroom(Classroom classroom)
    {
        if (classroom.IsClassroomFull)
        {
            attendingClassroom.Add(classroom);
            classroom.AddStudent(this);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Class is full!");
        }
    }
}

public class Classroom
{
    const int studentLimit = 20;
    private string classroomName;
    private Teacher headTeacher;
    private List<Student> studentsInClassroom = new List<Student>();

    public Classroom(string classroomName)
    {
        ClassroomName = classroomName;
    }

    public string ClassroomName { get => classroomName; private set => classroomName = value; }

    public bool IsClassroomFull => studentsInClassroom.Count > studentLimit;

    private bool HasTeacher() => headTeacher != null;

    public void SetTeacher(Teacher teacher)
    {
        if (HasTeacher())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Class already has a teacher !");
        }
        else
        {
            headTeacher = teacher;
        }
    }

    public void WriteHeadTeacherName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(headTeacher.TeacherName);
    }

    public void AddStudent(Student student)
    {
        studentsInClassroom.Add(student);
    }
}
```

When I add a student into the class,
the *AttendingClassroom* inside of the *Student* will have the *ClassroomName* and
the *studentsInClassroom* inside the *Classroom* will have the *StudentName*.
As you can see, if I use the *AttendToClassroom* method, everything will be okay.
But since the *AddStudent* method is **public** , it can be used and then only the *studentInClassroom* have the new property added. How can I prevent this or maybe fix this code?

Comment: Unrelated: `if (classroom.IsClassroomFull)` should be `if (!classroom.IsClassroomFull)`

Comment: To the question: You could use a combination of "Visitor Pattern" and explicitly implemented interfaces. OR (and I'd actually promote that) keep them completely unrelated (= no interdependency) and instead have a third class that abstracts the Student/Classroom relation.

Comment: Consider to create class `University` containing all students, all rooms and one more list (?) for "students in rooms".

Comment: thanks sir just try to use expression-bodied so some of those logic got inverted.

Comment: Happens to the best ;) But there's another quirk in this part: It's not thread safe. You could end up trying to add to a full classroom despite checking, if this is used multithreaded.

Comment: I would also suggest adding a coordinator class - and as a side note - this code `public string StudentName { get => studentName; private set => studentName = value; }` makes no sense. You should use auto-implemented properties unless you actually have logic in them - so change to `public string StudentName { get; private set; }`. On that note, I would consider having this property readonly as you already set the student's name in the constructor of the class.